# AngularJS: Recommendation on rendering different view when HTTP 404

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service, angularjs-routing

**What I am doing**

- I am trying to create a service which loads the user budgets for current month. The code looks like

  $scope.thisMonthBudgetSummary = function () {
          console.log('retrieving budget summary');

  ```
      var date = new Date();
      BudgetSummary.get({'month': date.getMonth() + 1, 'year': date.getFullYear()},
          function () {
              // success
          },
          function (error) {
              //error
              console.log('error:', error.status);
          })
  };
  ```

**Problem**
- I want to render a different view on Single Page when HTTP response is `404`, what is the recommendation on that? I am confused
  - I believe its not a good idea to hard code the template name in Controller

Comment: I think you should redirect to a 404 route if you don't want to hard code the template name

Answer (score 1):

An `$http` interceptor is certainly one way, in your application configuration you could do:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', '$location', function ($q, $location) {
                return {
                    'request': function (config) {
                        return config || $q.when(config);
                    },
                    'requestError': function (rejection) {
                        return $q.reject(rejection);
                    },
                    'response': function (response) {
                        return response || $q.when(response);
                    },
                    'responseError': function (rejection) {
                        if (rejection.status == "404") {
                           $location.path("/yourErrorRoute")
                        }
                        return $q.reject(rejection);
                    }
                };
}])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting a default functionality across your app, @Mohammad Sepahvand's answer works. If you simply want a one-off for that request, you can do:

```
var date = new Date();
BudgetSummary.get({'month': date.getMonth() + 1, 'year': date.getFullYear()},
    function (data, status, headers, config)  {
        //check your status here-->
        if (status === '200'){
            $location.path('/path/to/other/route');
        }
    },
    function (data, status, headers, config){
        //check your status here-->
        if (status === '404'){
            $location.path('/path/to/other/route');
        }
    })
};
```